# Reddit RSS feed, more than just the 25 results?

Tags: api, reddit

I'm trying to parse through the subreddits on http://reddit.com for the links, but so far I'm blocked by the limit of the 25 results given (say when visiting http://www.reddit.com/r/apple+programming.rss).

Does anyone know if there is either...

- A URL parameter to display more results
- There is another method to fetch more results? (looking at the [reddit api wiki](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki), I'm not seeing anything for fetching links from subreddit)

Answer (score 26):

Taken from [a prior revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8292143/3):

---

I had overlooked the simplest answer of them all. Matching the same parameters that the subreddits use themselves:

```
http://reddit.com/r/[subreddit].[rss/json]?limit=[limit]&after=[after]
```